# Meaning of "bidi-bidi-bum"

Tags: tefilla, music, popular-culture

In Fiddler on the Roof, in Tevye's song "[If I Were a Rich Man](http://youtu.be/Pl7BVr36bbs)," there is a line "all day long I'd bidi-bidi-bum." According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_I_Were_a_Rich_Man_%28song%29) this is a reference to prayer.

> A repeated phrase throughout the song, "all day long I'd
>   bidi-bidi-bum," is often misunderstood to refer to Tevye's desire not
>   to have to work. However, the phrase "bidi-bidi-bum" is a reference to
>   the practice of Jewish prayer[citation needed], in particular
>   davening.

However, Wikipedia says a citation is needed. Is Wikipedia correct?

Along those lines, is there any significance to other lines in the song that are not English words? I thought they were nonsense syllables, but if "bidi-bidi-bum" is meaningful, maybe other lines are too.

Comment: John, welcome to Judaism.SE and thank you for the interesting question. I can't think of any prayer that that references, but let's see what the community has to say. I look forward to seeing you around!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In [this interview](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=131092712) with Terry Gross (around 5:08), those lyrics' author, [Sheldon Harnick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldon_Harnick), says that he basically made up syllables that he thought would "give the effect" of "Chassidic chanting," despite not being familiar with such chanting from his own background. The first person to play Tevye, [Zero Mostel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Mostel), then replaced the syllables Harnick had written with ones that Mostel thought would be more authentic, based on his background.

So, I wouldn't ascribe too much significance to the particular syllables used in *Fiddler*. There is definitely a history of Jewish [Chazanim (cantors)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazzan) embellishing their singing of prayers with non-semantic syllables, but I'm not sure if there was ever any particular significance in the practice itself or the particular syllables chosen, other than in their effect in enhancing the aesthetic and emotional impact of the sung prayers.

Answer (score 0):

Theory: Simply imitative of or resembling the (nonsense?) sound "Ciri-biri-bom" from the [1960 Yiddish play and song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israil_Bercovici#Works_for_theater).
 (C as in Charlie)

Which is in turn imitative of or resembling "Ciribiribin," [1898 Piedmontese ballad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciribiribin).
The nonsense phrase Ciribiribin seems imitative of the words in its first line, especially "che bel" -- "how beautiful":

```
Ciribiribin! Che bel facin, / che bej ujin, che bel nasin. / Ciribiribin! Che bel bochin...<br>
```

Translation: Ciribiribin!  What a beautiful face, what beautiful eyes, what beautiful little nose! Chiribiribin, What a beautiful mouth...

Fiddler opened in 1964, so I'm guessing it was written shortly before then.