# Why does Rabba bar Mari in the Talmud quote Ben Sira as a part of “the Writings” when it is not in the Ketuvim section of the Tanakh?

Tags: talmud-gemara, tanach, rabbis, apocrypha, ketuvim

As revealed in [the answer here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/97293/does-anything-in-the-tanakh-resemble-the-quote-each-shall-seek-his-own-kind), in [Bava Kama 92b](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Kamma.92b.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=bi), Rava asks Rabba bar Mari for the source of a popular saying, and Rabba bar Mari answers with five different sources for it. The third verse, which is attributed to "the Writings," is from the Book of Ben Sira 13:17

> א"ל רבא לרבה בר מרי מנא הא מילתא דאמרי אינשי מטייל ואזיל דיקלא בישא
>   גבי קינא דשרכי אמר ליה דבר זה כתוב בתורה שנוי בנביאים ומשולש בכתובים
>   ותנן במתניתין ותנינא בברייתא
>
> Rava said to Rabba bar Mari: From where is this matter derived whereby
>   people say: A bad palm tree strolls and goes to be among a grove of
>   barren trees, i.e., bad people seek out other bad people? Rabba bar
>   Mari said to him: This matter is written in the Torah, repeated in the
>   Prophets, and triplicated in the Writings, and we learned it in a
>   mishna, and we learned it in a baraita.
>
> כתוב בתורה דכתיב (בראשית כח, ט) וילך עשו אל ישמעאל שנוי בנביאים דכתיב
>   (שופטים יא, ג) ויתלקטו אל יפתח אנשים רקים ויהיו עמו ומשולש בכתובים
>   דכתיב (בן סירא יג, יד) כל עוף למינו ישכון ובני אדם לדומה לו תנן במתני'
>   כל המחובר לטמא טמא כל המחובר לטהור טהור ותנינא בברייתא רבי אליעזר אומר
>   לא לחנם הלך זרזיר אצל עורב אלא מפני שהוא מינו
>
> Rabba bar Mari explains each of the sources. It is written in the
>   Torah, as it is written: “And so Esau went to Ishmael” (Genesis 28:9).
>   It is repeated in the Prophets, as it is written: “And there were
>   gathered vain fellows to Yiftah, and they went out with him” (Judges
>   11:3). And it is triplicated in the Writings, as it is written: All
>   fowl will live with its kind, and men with those like him (Book of Ben
>   Sira 13:17). We learned it in a mishna (Kelim 12:2): All that is
>   attached to that which is ritually impure is ritually impure; all that
>   is attached to that which is ritually pure is ritually pure. And we
>   learned it in a baraita: Rabbi Eliezer says: Not for naught did the
>   starling go to the raven but because it is its kind, as it too is a
>   non-kosher bird.

Unlike Catholics and Orthodox Christians, Jews do not count the Book of Ben Sira as canonical Scripture. It is not included in the Ketuvim section of the Jewish Tanakh. Why, then, does Rabba bar Mari in the Talmud quote Ben Sira as a part of “the Writings”?

Comment: Maybe Rabba bar Mari considered it to be part of the Ketuvim. Certain rabbis in the Talmud seemed to be fond of the Book of Ben Sirah.

Comment: Very similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36746/759 if not duplicate

Comment: Are you sure כתובים in that context is the כ in תנ"ך? Maybe it's like דברי הימים which is a generic term not only for a book in tanach but Chronicles of a generic king. So too Writings is a collection of writings by... someone.

Comment: @ezra The problem with that theory is that Rabba bar Mari is an amora, and the list of Ketuvim is given in [a barayta](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%91), earlier than Rabba bar Mari

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excellent Question!

As far as I can tell, this was first asked by the Geonim (Teshuvos Hageonim Sha'arei Teshuvah 121, according to this article, it was asked by R' Nissim Gaon to R' Hai Gaon, and see also Teshuvas Hageonim Musafia/Lik 27), who answered that the classification of "kesuvim" is not literal here, but rather, that they are "written" because the rabbis needed to write those words for proofs and other topics.

> וששאלתם הא דאמור רבנן בב"ק (דף צ"ב ע"ב) דבר זה משולש בכתובים כל עוף למינו ישכון ובן אדם לדומה לו ואינו בכתובים הכין הוא אלו דברי בן סירא הן וכתובים היו לפי שהוצרכו רבנן לכתוב מדבריו והם כתובים לראיות ולעניינים אבל לא בכתבי הקדש ועוד רגילין רז"ל שאומרים טעם המקרא שלא בלשון הכתוב כדאמרינן מהיות טוב אל תקרא רע ומקשינן ומי כתיב כי האי גוונא ומהדרינן כי הוא אל תמנע טוב מבעליו וכתיב הכא נמי הולך את חכמים יחכם:

h/t to IsraelReader in the comments, who notes that this was also the approach of Maharatz Chiyus/Chajes in his commentary to that Gemara. (I would assume that he is not the only one who follows their lead.)

The Maharal (on this gemara) has a interesting take.  He suggests that it may have been in another book that we hold in higher regard than Ben Sira, but that was simply lost:

> התו' מפרשים והוא ספר בן סירא ואני תמה למה הוצרכו לומר זה כי ספר בן סירא הוא דהא הרבה ספרים נאבדו מישראל כגון מדרש נוח והרבה ספרים כיוצא בזה ובאלו הספרים נראה שהיה כתוב דבר זה והוא נקרא כתובים.

In a later answer, the Alei Tamar (Makkos 2, dibbur hamaschil sha'alu) explains that Kesuvim is a short form for either 1) Kisvei Hakodesh 2) Kisvei Chochmah (or technically both , I guess), and obviously, here it is related to the latter...

> וכתבו התוס' שהוא בספר בן סירא (פי"ג), וכן בכמ"ק שכתוב בספר בן סירא, שאמנם "כתובים" הוא שם מקוצר והשם המלא לספרים החיצונים הוא "כתבי חכמה", וכן קראו המעתיק הקדמון של ספר בן סירא בסוף הספר, חכמת בן סירא, וכ"ה שמו בספרי כת"י וכן בסורית, חכמתא דבר סירא, בניגוד לספרי רוה"ק ששמם המלא הוא "כתבי קודש".

---

Some other (less-sourced) possibilities:

Perhaps based on [this comment](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Leviticus.26.6.1?lang=he&p2=Bartenura_on_Torah%2C_Leviticus.26.6.1&lang2=he) of RO Bartenura, we can say that if it is oft-quoted (as it is here) or used in a religious context, it would be considered as if it was a Passuk:

> וכן הוא אומר עושה שלום ובורא את הכל. אע"ג דאין זה פסוק במקרא הואיל וקבעוהו רבנן בתפלת יוצר חשיב ליה כמקרא מלא. וכן יש בדומה לזה בגמרא במקומות הרבה שמביא האמרים מספר בן סירא ומקומות אחרים

Perhaps some individual opinions considered it part of kesuvim (I'm not starting with sources for this now, just saying it's a possibility, see comments above)

Perhaps it is simply to assign it honor.

Comment: See also the notes of Maharitz Chayos (Bava Kamma, ad loc.) who (on his own) says something similar to the Teshuvos Hageonim cited in the answer. [Perhaps you would consider editing this into the answer].